# How do I make a tag in the body to properly show

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

```
xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><html><a href="#">the new link</a></html></root>';
```

These variables were my

```
 $(function(){
xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><html><a href="#">the new link</a></html></root>';
$xmls =$($.parseXML( xml ));

$('button').on('click',function(){
    console.log($xmls.find('html > *')[0]);
    $('body').append($xmls.find('html > *')[0]);
});
})
```

Added A tag does not work

pre tags will be displayed as A tag

http://jsfiddle.net/GgXEp/1/

Comment: which tag is not properly showing?

Comment: @Sachin <a> tag is showing as plain text

Comment: the only thing i can think of is try getting the actual text node and url from the anchor, and on javascript create an anchor using link = document.createElement('a'); then link.setAttribute('href', url) and link.innerHTML = textNode, and append it to the node you want

Comment: @aleation the <a> tag is not the only tag that I want to import from XML, all other HTML Tags imported as plain Text as well. also the innerHTML doesn't work because doctype is XML.

Comment: See my answer if your issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MeJ8N/3/)

I fixed it. It works in every browser. It took me some time so i hope it works.
I also added another link in the xml document to make it visible that it only selects the element with the index of 0:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    HTML = $($.parseHTML(xmls.find('root').text()));
    console.log(HTML[0]);
    $('body').append(HTML[0]);
});
```

Comment: Works fine if you migrate from jquery 1.10.1 to 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

After 1 hour of processing and thinking, I will come with a workaround for you:

First, update jquery library to `1.9.1` (maybe is an issue with 1.10.1 because console gave me Access Denied in IE & Opera) and then let's store found element in a jquery variable like:

```
$element = xmls.find('html > *').first();
```

Then let's create an anchor using jquery:

```
$a = $("<a>").attr( "href", $element.attr("href") ).text( $element.text() );
```

After that, let's do addition in button on click action:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
   $('body').append($a);
});
```

Of course, the proof: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GgXEp/4/)

Comment: the <a> tag is not the only tag that I want to import from XML, all other HTML Tags imported as plain Text as well. also the innerHTML doesn't work because doctype is XML.